# Azure pipeline CI compilation no update all files

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have a build done for a ASP.Net project.
In code I have updated the names of several fields in an HTML but, when the build is launched and published, it never updates the changes I have made.
It always takes the original version to create the artifact.
I have deleted and created the build from scratch, but it always does the same thing.

What can I do?
I have more builds just like this one and this doesn't happen.

Best regards,

Comment: Can you share yaml files of build and release?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the commit version of your pipeline?

It may due to your pipeline using another branch, which is the original version.

[image: commit id]